# How to style in this hidden/show function?

Tags: javascript

```
// A function that hides or shows a selected element
function hideOrShow1() {
    
    // Select the element with id "theDIV"
    var x = document.getElementById("popup_roadmap_info_picture_1");
    
    // If selected element is hidden
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
    
      // Show the hidden element
      x.style.display = "none";
      
      // Else if the selected element is shown
    } else {
    
      // Hide the element
      x.style.display = "block";
      x.style.transition = "3s";
    }
  }
```

I want the element which will be display to have a transition. Is it possible with js.
NOTE: x.style.transition is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform transitions if the element is toggled to `display: none`. You could use the `opacity` property or the `height and width` properties

Answer (score 0):

Which property are you trying to transition? You can't transition display states from `none` to `block`, hence why it might seem that `style.transition` is not working.

You could transition the opacity, transform scale, width or height for an appearing/disappearing effect.

Comment: How can I make a appering/disappering effect?

Comment: See the example that @zer00ne provided for a more detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

`display: none` to `display:block` doesn't have any steps in-between it's like a light switch off/on. You'll need to use a property that has a number value like `opacity`. When you use the `.style` attribute, you are overwriting everything within it. So if you do this:

```js
// 
x.style.opacity = "1";
x.style.transition = "3s";
```

If you look in devtools and look at the HTML layout you should see:

```html
<div class='popup' style='opacity:1'></div> <!---->
```

Then this:

```html
<div class='popup' style='transition:3s'></div> <!---->
```

You need this:

```html
<div class='popup' style='transition:3s;opacity:1'></div> <!---->
```

In order to do the whole rulest with all of the properties and values at once you use `.cssText` property like this:

```js
x.style.cssText = "transition: 3s; opacity:1;";  //
```

```js
function popup() {
  let x = document.querySelector(".popup");
  if (x.style.opacity === "0") {
    x.style.cssText = "transition: all 3s; font-size: 100px; opacity: 1;";
  } else {
    x.style.cssText = "transition: all 3s; font-size: 0; opacity: 0;";
  }
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick = popup;
```

```html
<button>BOO</button>
<div class='popup' style='opacity: 0; font-size:0;'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok for you?
p.s. You cannot click an element that has display none. That's why you should rather work with e.g. opacity.

```js
// Select the element with id "theDIV"
var x = document.getElementById("popup_roadmap_info_picture_1");
x.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // If selected element is hidden
    if (x.classList.contains('transition-none')) {
    
      x.classList.remove('transition-none');
      // Show the hidden element
      x.classList.add('transition-block');
      
      // Else if the selected element is shown
    } else {
    
      // Hide the element
      x.classList.add('transition-none');
      x.classList.remove('transition-block');
    }
});
```

```css
.transition-block {
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.transition-none {
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup_roadmap_info_picture_1">Hallo</div>
```